# Angularjs directives working only in controller file

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So, using angularJS, I want to separate my directives in their own files for more clarity.
I tried some suggestions I found here and elsewhere but it didn't work.

For now my directive is in the controller file which is also the file where I define my module.

Controller.js :

```
var app = angular.module("viewerApp", ["ngDialog"]);

app.config(['ngDialogProvider', function (ngDialogProvider) {
    ngDialogProvider.setDefaults({
        className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
        plain: false,
        showClose: true,
        closeByDocument: true,
        closeByEscape: true,
        appendTo: false,
        preCloseCallback: function () {
            console.log('default pre-close callback');
        }
    });
}]);

app.controller('viewerController', function ($scope, $rootScope, ngDialog) {

/*
Here I have most of my $scope manipulations and functions
*/

});

app.controller('InsideCtrl', function ($scope, ngDialog) {

/*
Small controller to handle some dialog event
*/

});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        template: 'Directive, lang: {{ currentLanguage }}'

    };
})
```

Then in my HTML file :

```
<body ng-keypress="handleKeys($event)" ng-controller="viewerController">

{{ "Default : " + defaultLanguage + " - Current : " + currentLanguage }}<br />
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

So this way it is working fine, I got my test template displayed just like I want.

But when I move the code corresponding to the directive to a new file, it stops working.

FYI I tried the following in the new file :

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        template: 'Directive, lang: {{ currentLanguage }}'

    }
});
/* ----------------- */
angular.module("viewerApp", ["ngDialog"]).directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        template: 'Directive, lang: {{ currentLanguage }}'

    };
})
/* ----------------- */
angular.module("viewerApp").directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        template: 'Directive, lang: {{ currentLanguage }}'

    };
})
```

How can I fix this ?

Regards.

Comment: and you have included your directive.js file using a `<script>` tag in your pages?

Comment: Yes I did.
I found a solution I posted as answer before I consult any answer here.
But I'm not sure this is a proper way  to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're loading your new directives file and also that:

- either your global `app` variable is available to it
- or retreive the module using `angular.module("viewerApp")`

But you must have that reference to the module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how are you defining the module to which the controller/directive are getting associated, so I'll start afresh.

We'll start by defining the module somewhere, let's say in the controller file:

```
viewerModule = angular.module("viewerApp", ["ngDialog"])
viewerModule.controller('viewerController' ... )
```

And in the directive file you'll just have to reference the module with

```
viewerModule = angular.module("viewerApp")
viewerModule.directive('myDirective' ... )
```

Remember, **no square brackets to reference** the module!

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

after you create **myDirective.js**, make sure of the following:

**1.** load **myDirective.js** to the html page where you loaded the controller, but ***after*** that controller:

```
<script src="path/to/myDirective.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**2.** create your html template for that directive (**my-directive.html**)

**3.** back to your directive script file, inside the **return** object, add the following:

```
restrict: "E",
templateUrl: '/app/templates/search.html'
```

**4.** now in the base/parent html file, add `<my-directive></my-directive>` to the `body` element

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just managed to make it work by adding a new module containing the directive.
Then I added this module in the main module dependencies.

directive file :

```
var app = angular.module("myDirective-directive", []);

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        template: 'Directive, lang: {{ currentLanguage }}'
    };
});
```

And in controller file I changed my module declaration like this :

```
var app = angular.module('viewerApp', ["ngDialog", "myDirective-directive"]);
```

Is this solution OK or is it not recommended to do it this way ?

Answer (score 0):

declare app variable if it is not global in your directive file [Check out this link this will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20613455/4713154)

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest you to use that style for angular module.
Don't use it like this

```
var app = angular.module("example",[...]);
```

It's good style to use an angular module like this way.

```
angular.module("example", [...]) ...
...
...
```

Inside another file

```
angular.module("example").directive(...) // or something else
```