# AngularJs external file controllers and directives: how to write them correctly?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an app.js file where I specify my dependencies:

```
angular.module("myApp", ['angular-jwt', 'chart.js']).config(...)
```

I want an external file for directives, so in directives.js I write:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive(...)
```

same thing for the controller.js:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('pokerstrazzkCtrl', function($scope, $http, jwtHelper) { ...
```

and this is the include script order in the html file:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/auth0/angular-jwt/master/dist/angular-jwt.js"></script>
    <script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    <script src="directives.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
```

when displaying in the browsers I get no console errors and source code of the page is exactly what it should but I only see the background, no text or other elements. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is your **controller name** and **ng-app** added to the html declarations?

Comment: ng-controller should be pokerstrazzkCtrl

Comment: yes yes, sorry, I rewrote the code for simplicity, ng-app and ng-controller are fine!

Comment: please create a fiddle

Comment: P.S. when all the code was in a single js file it perfectly worked!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one,

Declare a global variable for your module.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['angular-jwt', 'chart.js']).config(...)
```

And then use this variable for representing your module.

```
myApp.directive(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally figured out why it wasn't working before but the really correct way to define modules, directives and controllers without the use of global variable is the following:

```
// app.js - main file, where the app module is defined
angular.module('yourApp', ['yourDependencies']).config(function Config($service1, $service2) {


// directives.js
angular.module('yourApp')

.directive('yourDirective', function() { ...

// controller.js
angular.module('yourApp').controller('yourController', function($service1, $two, ...) { ...
```

Of course the order in which you include the file in  is fundamental:

```
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="directives.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
```

app.js must precede all of his children (controller.js and directives.js) or it won't work!!! That's why it wasn't working for me. Everything was fixed when I inverted directives.js and controller.js

Comment: Cool, earlier I did not see the order of your script files , :)

Answer (score 0):

> **Use the same variable var 'myApp' in external files**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

> in exernal file controller.js

```
myApp.controller('pokerstrazzkCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
 $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

> in exernal file directives.js

```
myApp.directive('myCustomer', function() { 
return {
template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
  };
});
```

Comment: yes I could do that and thanks for the answer, but I've read it's not a good practice using variables for angular modules, etc. Is this the only way to make it work?

Comment: refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612484/angularjs-separating-directive-files-but-staying-on-the-same-module

Comment: We are taught to avoid global variable like a plague XD. While it's ok to use global variable in this case, but some part in me got the uneasy feeling...