# Angularjs: How to create separate files for the main-module and the main-controller

Tags: angularjs, file, module, controller, modularity

I've the same issues as in [how-to-create-separate-angularjs-controller-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087627/how-to-create-separate-angularjs-controller-files), but it seems to be a little bit more complicated: I want to separate my module declaration and the "MAIN-Controller" into separate files, say app.js and appCtrl.js.

app.js contains:

```
angular.module('app', []);
```

appCtrl.js contains:

```
angular.module('app').controller('appCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.model = { MyValue : "coucou" };
}]);
```

Following code is ok:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"/>
    <script src="scripts/ctrl/appCtrl.js"/>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    My value = {{model.MyValue}}

</body>
</html>
```

but following code is NOT OK:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    My value = {{model.MyValue}}

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"/>
    <script src="scripts/ctrl/appCtrl.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Angular throws the Error: "[ng:areq] Argument 'appCtrl' is not a function, got undefined" Unfortunately, the latter is the recommanded way to include angular and the modules...

Is there a solution to this issue? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

appCtrl.js:

```
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.model = { MyValue : "coucou" };
```

}]);

Comment: this is exactly what I do! But it fails if the <Script> statements are at the bottom of the index.html file.

Comment: Thank you, the issue was actually the self-closing Script-Tag `<SCRIPT src=""/>` which is buggy in Chrome, as stated in [this other stackoverflow question][1]. 
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Answer (score 0):

I would use angular modules/injection functionalities :

app.js contains:

```
angular.module('app', ['app.controllers']);
```

appCtrl.js contains :

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
    .controller('appCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.model = { MyValue : "coucou" };
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you, the issue was actually the self-closing Script-Tag `<SCRIPT src=""/>` which is buggy in Chrome, as stated in [this other stackoverflow question][1]. 
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work