# How to bind controllers contained in a folder to views in angularjs dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a controller in a folder named controller at the root.
I have view that I want to attach to the corresponding views when the route changes. I am using angular-ui-router.

controllers/one.js

```
angular.module('sub',["ui.router"]).config(function($stateProvider){
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "/login",
        views: {
            "viewA": {
                templateUrl: "login.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('register', {
        url: "/register",
        views: {
            "viewA": {
                templateUrl: "register.html" 
            }
        }
    })
    .state('upload', {
        url: "/upload",
        views: {
            "viewA": {
                templateUrl: "upload.html" 
            }
        }
    })
})
```

test.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="sub">

    <head>
        <title>AngularJS: UI-Router Quick Start</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body class="container">

      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <a class="brand" ui-sref="index">Quick Start</a>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li><a ui-sref="index">Home</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="register">Register</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="upload">upload</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
          <div class="well" ui-view="viewA"></div>        
        </div>
      </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Controllers/one.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Controllers/loginController.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Controllers/uploadController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Controllers/registerController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-ui-router.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

login.html

```
<div ng-controller="loginController">
<p>
             UserName: 
            <input id="director" type="text" ng-model="mUserName"/>
        </p>

        <p>
             Password: 
            <input id="actor" type="text" ng-model="mPassWord"/>
        </p>
        <button ng-click="login()">Login</button>
 </div>
```

Controllers/LoginController.js

```
angular.module('subsd',["ngCookies"]).controller('loginController', ['$http','$scope','$cookies',function($http,$scope,$cookies) {})]);
```

If I mention 'sub' instead of 'subsd' in loginController.js the routing stops working.

Answer (score 2):

The final answer includes few things to do:

1. Remove `<div ng-controller="loginController">` from the *login.html* template file.
2. Move the `'ngCookies'` dependency to the `sub` module definition in *controllers/one.js* file (`angular.module('sub',["ui.router", "ngCookies"])`).
3. In the *controllers/logincontroller.js* file change the module name from `subsd` to `sub` back again and remove the second argument from the `sub` module invoke, to make it look like this: `angular.module('sub').controller(...)`.

When you changed the module name before, you were trying to **re-define** it, which is an error.

This

```
angular.module('moduleName', [...dependencies])
```

is the module **setter**, while this

```
angular.module('moduleName')
```

is the module **getter**.

Comment: I made these mistakes, while making the code modular. Everthing was working fine, when I had all the controllers in a single file. Thank you for pointing the issues in code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```js
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "/login",
        views: {
            "viewA": {
                templateUrl: "login.html",

                // THIS ?
                controller: "LoginController"
            }
        }
    })        
})
```

**Also** remember to remove the `ng-controller` attribute from the view.

Comment: I have tried this, but it does not work. Also my controller is in a folder named Controllers.

Comment: Describe _"doesn't work"_. What __exactly__ didn't work? Did you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I encounter this error, Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/ng/areq?p0=loginController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)

Comment: You defined your controller with capital letters "LoginController" and tried to include it with the first letter as non-capital "loginController". __It matters__. Also remember to include the controller file with `<script src="Controllers/LoginController.js"></script>`.

Comment: I have made the changes, but still the same error is thrown

Comment: For 100% you must have some other error you're not telling me about. I prepared a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvow8938/) to show that it works.

Comment: Ok, I get it. You've put the controller in the wrong module. Change this `angular.module('sub').controller('loginController'...` to this `angular.module('myapp').controller('loginController'...`.

Comment: If I do the above change, then the route does not work. The views are not displayed on clicking the links.

Comment: Now I am pretty much sure that, there is something wrong with the modules defined as 'sub' and 'myapp'. If I change 'sub' to 'myapp' I do not see the Error:[ng:areq] in the console but on clicking the links the views do not change, whereas earlier the views did change on traversing the links.

Comment: I removed the controller attr from yapp.js and moved the yapp.js code to one.js.  angular.module('sub',[]).config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: "/login",
            views: {
                "viewA": {
                    templateUrl: "login.html"
                }
            }
        })})

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71747/discussion-between-sham-and-matewka).