# Partial view ng-click not working when using two different controller files

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on MVC4 with angular JS and using ng-include to call a partial view inside my main view. Issue comes when I am trying to click a button inside my partial view.

I have two different controllers in angular, one for main and other one for a partial view both are working under same module.

My file structure is as follows

Scripts..

|
--Main.js

|--ProjectPage.js

(Main.js)

```
var app = angular.module("Layout", []);
app.controller("LoadPage", function ($scope) {
    $scope.templateUrl = '/Home/DefaultPage';
};
```

(ProjectPage.js)

```
angular.module("Layout")
    .controller("CNTRL", function ($scope) {
    $scope.clickBtn1 = function () {
        alert("ABU");
    };
  });
```

and this is the HTML, I am using for partial page

```
<body ng-app="Layout" ng-controller="CNTRL">
<button ng-click="clickBtn1 ()" id="click">click</button>
```

The partial view is working fine when its called up independently(not inside the main view). No error is coming inside the browser but click event is not working.

Comment: why your partial html again contain an body tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably because you are calling the "app" twice. Once in your layout (html) page and then in your partial page. You can fix this by replacing:

```
<body ng-app="newLayout" ng-controller="CNTRL">
```

With:

```
<div ng-controller="CNTRL">
  <!-- button code here -->
```

**NOTE:** The change from `body` to `div` (can be any html container tag) and removal of `ng-app` directive.

Comment: It has started working but why we need to change the parent tag from body to div ? If I am keeping the ng-controller in my body its not working.

Comment: You need to change the partial page's tag from `body` to `div` (or any other container tag e.g. `section`) because there's already a `body` tag in the layout file (if I'm not mistaken about MVC4). And you with html, you can only have 1 `body` tag. You also need to remove `ng-app` from the partial because like the `body` tag, you only need 1 `ng-app` directive

Answer (score 0):

Here! You have same module name so it will consider first one.
Just different name both and it will works..

> main.js

```
var app = angular.module("Layout", []);
app.controller("LoadPage", function ($scope) {
    $scope.templateUrl = '/Home/DefaultPage';
};
```

> ProjectPage.js

```
angular.module("newLayout")
    .controller("CNTRL", function ($scope) {
    $scope.clickBtn1 = function () {
        alert("ABU");
    };
});
```

> Body content

```
<body ng-app="newLayout" ng-controller="CNTRL">
<button ng-click="clickBtn1 ()" id="click">click</button>
```

Comment: I want to use the very same module. And if I use your code it will give me error as dependency is not defined for new module. Please have a look here you will get better understanding of what I am looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087627/how-to-create-separate-angularjs-controller-files

Comment: Just add  app = angular.module("Layout", ['newLayout']);   and angular.module("newLayout",[])         your error go..

Comment: please check spelling mistake.. your code is proper but somewhere minor mistake of spelling in name...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79741/discussion-between-uttam-panara-and-rahul).