# Is it possible to put AngularJS Controllers into multiple files whilst avoiding loads of script tags in the HTML file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been [reading some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087627/how-to-create-separate-angularjs-controller-files?rq=1) and [Brian Ford](http://briantford.com/blog/huuuuuge-angular-apps) about how to break out my controllers into multiple files so I can keep everything a bit more organised and easy-to-find.

I am somewhat new to all of this, and just can't get my head around something.

If I create Controller1.js, Controller2.js, Controller3.js, etc, do I need to then have Script tags in my HTML file for *each* one e.g.:

```
<script src="app/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="app/js/app.js"></script>    
<script src="app/js/config.js"></script>
<script src="app/js/services.js"></script>
<script src="app/js/controller1.js"></script>
<script src="app/js/controller2.js"></script>
<script src="app/js/controller3.js"></script>
```

... and so on for all 57 controllers I have?

I'm building an app using a theme and it comes with an example. In it he has

```
<script src="app/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="app/js/app.js"></script>
```

at the bottom of his index.html file - and that's it. There's reference to Gulp and Grunt, but I'm not familiar with these tools. I've also stumbled into RequireJS. Head spinning about which way to go.

Any pointers or can anyone explain in a bit more dumb-ass friendly language how this is done?

Comment: requireJS is the way to go, just give it another try :p

Comment: can use task tools like gulp or grunt to put the tags in the page for you...and later do a build process that minifies and concatenates the files for production

Comment: Use a bundler like browserify or webpack to create a single js file, and have just <script src="app/app.js"></script> in your html.

Comment: @charlietfl has it right. This when set you up well. It gives you complete control over how the files are managed for a build intended for a given environment.