# Angular: How to split (divide) controller's script?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just recently build a web based app with angular. I really love how angular handle Model-View-Controller, so I build my controller to handle button click event, datepicker changed event, etc while business logic is being controlled by the model. The problem is: the more button or control I put into my view, the larger my controller script is .

For example: If I have 2 buttons, my controller would be look like this:

```
$scope.onBtn1Clicked = function(){}
$scope.onBtn2Clicked = function(){}
```

So, what if I have 10 more buttons ? 10 more function ? 
I'm well aware about Angular's directive, but I don't want to write an directive if I will use it just once. 
So I think it is better to split/divide my controller into several "sub controller" files and joined them in my "main controller".

Can it be done ? Or anyone have other solution ?
Thx

PS: I know about [How to create separate AngularJS controller files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087627/how-to-create-separate-angularjs-controller-files) . But this is different: I already have separated my controllers to several files, so that a page in my application have one controller. The problem I have is that those controller become so large and impossible to maintain

Answer (score 1):

It depends:

- If function control some element behavior it should be inside [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
- If function contain some independent logic it should be inside [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) (or factory or provider)
- If function contain business logic it should [controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

**Also**: if some logic can be separated you need to put it into sub [controller](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/controllers/sharing-models-between-nested-controllers.html) (directive or service)

Comment: I guess that you're saying that I should write directives . Let's assume that I have a page with some panels/parts, each has its own directive. So what if those directive grow so large. should I split them again into many smaller directives ? I just want to know what is the best Angular practices to deal with this big-project issue that I have

Comment: also thank you for the article link about service above. Great and clear tutorial!

Comment: @denny yap you understand right, you should use directives and split them then its needed

Comment: well.. then I'm gonna need to write a lot of directives and controllers, so i guess my question is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087627/how-to-create-separate-angularjs-controller-files
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure, you can nest controllers

controllers

```
myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.timeOfDay = 'morning';
  $scope.name = 'Nikki';
}]);
myApp.controller('ChildController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Mattie';
}]);
myApp.controller('GrandChildController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.timeOfDay = 'evening';
  $scope.name = 'Gingerbread Baby';
}]);
```

and the markup

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>

    <div ng-controller="ChildController">
      <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>

      <div ng-controller="GrandChildController">
        <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JoppxUAiZRLccLCC12JW?p=preview)
[Explanation](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/basics/nestedcontrollers/)

Comment: Your Demo doesn't work, it's just a generic 'edit' link

Comment: @CharlyDelta thanks, updated :)

Comment: @evc: so what if I want to share variables and functions that accessible through all 'children' controller? and how about Dependency, like MainController must depend on GrandchildController ?

Comment: @denny its good then all controllers separated. It`s good if you share data between controllers by service https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services

Comment: @denny Look at `ChildController` controller, it doesn't have `$scope.timeOfDay`, so it will inherit it from `MainController`