# How to separate controllers in different files for angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a globale `routes` controller and want to create an additional controller for each page template.

It's done as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize', 'ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/test", {
            templateUrl:    "./templates/test.html",
            controller:     "testController"
        })
});

app.controller('test', function() {
    //...
});
```

**Question**:  how can I move the controller to it's own `testController.js` file? I tried it, but then the controller does not work anymore.

Which steps do I have to take if I extract the controller in its own file?

1. How can I get access to `var app` module variable from within testController.js?
2. Do I necessairly have to include each controller as new `<script src="js/testController.js"></script>` tag entry in my html templates? That would be cumbersome, as I want to split my application into many controllers, and that would result in many many imports.

Comment: You can use RequireJS to include other files, maybe this blog will help: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/

Comment: Why not concat all js files into single app.js?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create separate AngularJS controller files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087627/how-to-create-separate-angularjs-controller-files)

Answer (score 5):

You can access `app` by simply declaring it without dependencies:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp');
app.controller("testController", function() {

});
```

And yes, you need to include `testController.js` on every page that needs it.

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly -- Is there a part of the question I missed?

Comment: i mean the question is too easy, and the answer is also too easy

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly -- So your reason for downvoting is because the question is "easy"?