# Angularjs StreamHelperController is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I do understand why angular throws this error but i didn't find a solution that solves my case.

When angular encounter with ng-controller attribute, it tries to find injected controller named as the attribute value.

For example for my case:

Angular tries to find StreamHelperController in the injected controller list, when it doesn not find it, it throws

> "StreamHelperController is not a function"

.

Known Solution: Injecting controller before loading view layer.

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp');
 app.controller('StreamHelperController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {}]);
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="StreamHelperController ">
```

But the problem occurs when i load view before controller class. And this is my case. So how can i manage and solve this problem ?

ENV:
Angularjs 1.5.8

Comment: is missing module initialize: var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

Comment: I am not initializing module, trying to get initialized module. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20087682/1399830

Answer (score 0):

1. javascript is synchronous.
2. controller is the bond|connection between model and view, without it no communication.

   Thus, controller not defined at time will freeze the parsing.**Try using promise or some other asynchronous trick** or provide more info.