# Where can I define an injectable object so that it's available in all controllers and directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, factory

Similar to this question: [How to create separate AngularJS controller files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087627/how-to-create-separate-angularjs-controller-files)

I have a module that has controllers in several files, including controllers that are linked to directives. Where can I declare a factory such that it can be injected into all of them easily?

For example, in app.js I define the app level module
`var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);`

I would then expect to be able to define a factory in app.js like
`app.factory('myFactory', function() { return { myThing: myThing}; });`

And then be able to inject it into a controller that looked like

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', '$http', 'myFactory', 
    function ($scope, $http, myFactory) {}]);
```

But I get the error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Currently you have syntax error `app.factory('myFactory, function() {})`. It looks like you redefine myApp module with angular.module('myApp', []). Of course, it won't have myFactory, and it won't have ngRoute module loaded, too.

Comment: Edited for corrections and clarity.

Comment: Then I would say that getting `$injector:unpr` is not possible, at least for myFactory. The code above won't have problems with injecting myFactory to a controller.