# AngularJS not displaying the URL

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

Why **"main"** is not being displayed in the URL ? Here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/O3YFmJqyereOKhHXg8v1?p=preview).

index2.html is the working file. I have modified index2.html to index.html to include routing but it's not working.

app.js has routing configuration

```
(function() {

    var app1 = angular.module('plunker', ["ngRoute"]);
    app1.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when("/main", {
          templateUrl: "main.html",
          controller: "ControllerFile.js"
        })

      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/main"
      })
    })

  }   ());
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Ach, this isn't a picture, it's just your code. Then again: post your code here, not somewhere else on external resource.

Comment: but why?Plunker is a legit site.i have posted plunker links  before this question too?

Comment: 1. your controller name is `MainCtrl`, not `ControllerFile.js` 2. you have mismatching versions of angularjs and angular-route (both need to be the same - 1.6.2 - or whatever you chose) 3. there are some issues with [controller/service initiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087627/how-to-create-separate-angularjs-controller-files) (don't create new instances of `app`)

Comment: i fixed the code but still it's not displaying main in the url